# What do I need to update, to get the latest recyclerview methods?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

According to the docs, the latest recyclerview has [addOnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)), yet in android studio this method doesn't show up, but instead shows the deprechiated [setOnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener))method, but with no sign of it being depreciated.

Any help on what I need to update would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you just need to head over to the SDK Manager and update the support library and sdk ?

Comment: I'll try that and report back :)

Comment: @2Dee everything is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using support.v7 RecyclerView

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

And in build.grade

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: My compile statement was on 21 not 22. Thank you for the fix :)

Comment: glad you got it fixed ! When checking the docs, I expected to see a mention that the method was added in a recent API version but failed to see one, so good catch there on your part ;)

Comment: Sorry for interrupt, but I was looking for this for a few hours and I was about to ask for the same thing. I even asked on Android Dev forums (but the threads must be approved first). Glad to see that someone already asked it :P. (There it goes my *spiritual* accept).

Comment: I've had numerous occasions where I'm stumped as to why I cant see a certain method. Then I realize I'm using a slightly different class. All because of the support libraries...